# How to check what shell is running?

Tags: bash, shell, csh

I need to check if the script is running from `bash` or `csh`.

```
#!/bin/csh

if ( `echo $SHELL` != '/bin/tcsh' )
   echo 'Please run it in csh' 
   exit
endif
```

This code is giving

```
bash: g.csh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Uh, the hash-bang at the top should mean it always runs in csh. How are you invoking the script?

Comment: No, I some csh scripts I cant run it simply, At first I need to run csh in bash, then source the script

Comment: If someone tries to run your `csh` script with a different, incompatible shell, I'd say that's their problem, not your script's.

Comment: If `$SHELL` has the wrong value, why do you think that shell will be able to execute the `if` statement in the first place?

Comment: `$SHELL` is the user's login shell, not the current running shell.

Comment: @jordanm Awesome. That explains an issue I was having with [pow](https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/297#issuecomment-15207107)

Comment: I'm not sure you can assume any meaning for the value of `SHELL`; it's not mentioned in the POSIX specification.

Comment: Time to point out that if you're programming scripts for the C shell, the first problem is precisely that: you're using the wrong shell.  Use a real shell and leave sea shells on the C shore.  See [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) too.  The shebang line (which should be consistent with the test, but isn't) ensures that if someone invokes `g.csh` as a plain command like that, they get the correct shell executed.  If they run `bash g.csh`, then the syntax error is appropriate and don't fret about it; they're misusing the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a `then`. Try this.

```
#!/bin/csh

if ( "$SHELL" != '/bin/tcsh' ) then
   echo 'Please run it in csh' 
   exit
endif
```

Though it seems like the commenters are correct in that the hashbang will force csh.

Comment: I added `then`, but I am getting the same error when running the script from bash

Comment: I am running it from zsh and bash and it is working for me. I also changed the `$SHELL` part. Did you copy my code?

Comment: I copied your code and I am getting the same error when running the script from bash

Answer (score 6):

Check the variable $0 (the name of the file/shell in execution).
Trying

```
echo $0
```

under bash or csh gives

```
/bin/bash
```

or

```
csh
```

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty restricted if you want to use syntax that runs in both `bash` and `tcsh`. In fact, my `tcsh` doesn't even seem to set `SHELL`, which may be why you think you're still in `bash` -- if I launch `tcsh` from `bash`, `SHELL` is still `/bin/bash`. That said, if you really need to check, something like this could work (caveat: linux-specific):

```
test `readlink /proc/$$/exe` != `which tcsh` && echo you must use tcsh && exit 1
```

This works in both shells. Also note, that since `csh` is provided by the same binary as `tcsh` (at least it's that way for me), this will check for either `tcsh` *or* `csh`.

Comment: When I add this line to script and run it from bash, the script exits and also console window is closed :)

Comment: @Ashol: well now that will teach them to use the wrong shell! ;) It sounds like you are sourcing this script. In that case, try changing `exit` to `return`.

Answer (score 0):

This line should work in nearly any shell

```
sh -c "[ \"$SHELL\" = \"tcsh\" ] || { echo \"Please run in tcsh\"; exit 1; }" || exit
```

but I'm not sure that this is the best way to solve whatever problem it is you are trying to solve.